# Bash How to format a date

Tags: bash, shell, date

I want to grep a file with the following date format:

```
Thu Apr 24
```

At the moment I only have `date +"%d %m %Y"` and that's returning 24 04 2014.

How do I format to get "Thu Apr 24"?

So I need the day month and date?

Comment: `man date` might help.

Comment: If the mentioned string isn't a part of the filename, but a timestamp then there are _better ways_.

Answer (score 3):

[`man date`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) would suggest `date +"%a %b %d"`

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
date +"%a %b %d"
```

where

```
   %a     locale's abbreviated weekday name (e.g., Sun)

   %b     locale's abbreviated month name (e.g., Jan)

   %d     day of month (e.g., 01)
```